# Best way to iterate over a flow that read a motion sensor - java

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, motion-detection

I have a Raspberry PI and I use this sensor MPU-9150 for catch the motion.

I using this guide https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/beyond_beauty_javafx_i2c_parallax for wire the sensor to the PI, after the wiring I wrote a class based to the class shown on the guide.

Now the question is, consider the method written below that running into a separate thread read the sensor data.

As you can see this method use a cycle while( true ){} to iterate over a flow that read the data... i think that approach will kill the resources of the CPU so what is a better way for do that?

I hope I have been able to explain the problem to the best, So Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

```
private void readingSensorsV2() throws IOException {

    int gyroX;
    int gyroY;
    int gyroZ;
    int gyroX_last = 0;
    int gyroY_last = 0;
    int gyroZ_last = 0;

    while (true) {
        gyroData = new byte[6];

        // You can read one registry at a time,
        // or you can read multiple consecutive ones,
        // in our case we are reading 6 consecutive registries
        // from 0x43, meaning we are reading all the
        // gyroscope measurements.

        int r = device.read(0x43, gyroData, 0, 6);
        if (r != 6) {
            System.out.println("Error reading gyro data, < 6 bytes");
        }

        // Convert the values to integers, using the
        // helper method asInt
        gyroX = (asInt(gyroData[0]) * 256 + asInt(gyroData[1]));
        gyroY = (asInt(gyroData[2]) * 256 + asInt(gyroData[3]));
        gyroZ = (asInt(gyroData[4]) * 256 + asInt(gyroData[5]));

        if( accuracy<Math.abs( gyroX_last-gyroX ) || accuracy<Math.abs( gyroY_last-gyroY ) || accuracy<Math.abs( gyroZ_last-gyroZ ) ){
            for( GyroMovDet gyroListner : gyroListners ){
                gyroListner.onMove( gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ);
            }
        }

        gyroX_last = gyroX;
        gyroY_last = gyroY;
        gyroZ_last = gyroZ;

    }
}
```